# Map is not a function : {} JSON array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I just went from Vue to React and I'm a little lost on the iteration of an array.
With the same API, everything works with Vue but not with React.

Here is an example of an answer from my API:

```
{
  "blade": {
  "id":"1",
  "key":"blade"
  },
  "sword": {
  "id":"2",
  "key":"sword"
  }
}
```

I think the problem is that my API response returns an array but with the symbols `{}` and not `[]`

If the problem comes from this, how can I solve it?

This is my current code:

```
class ItemSelection extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [],
         };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://myapi.com/items.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ items: data }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            {
                this.state.items.map(item => (
                    <div>...</div>
                ))
            }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `items: {},` is not an array

Comment: `{}` means object, `[]`means array, if you confuse them you won't achieve anything

Comment: json is an object, and that object can contain arrays

Comment: `map` is array prototype `fn`, you cannot get it with `{}` / `object`. To iterate over object use `for..in` loop

Comment: @SatyamPathak: Or `Object.keys(object).map`.

Comment: You can use `Object.values(object)` to cast to an array, on which you can call `.map` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values
@S

Comment: Excuse me, I corrected my code, I had put[] and not {}
How do I do knowing I have an array variable?

Comment: That depends on what the API returns, check the documentation or their implementation.

Comment: your api response  is clearly not an `array` - You can't just undo what you mistaken you need to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is a Object.... you can use the function Object.values(items) to get a list of values and use the map function.

```
.then(data => this.setState({ items: Object.values(data) }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem with data = Array.from(data);

Answer (score 0):

`{}` denotes a JSON object, not an array, a map object is also treated in a similar way. Therefore, you can access the elements of the object/map using as below

```
<div v-for="item in items">
    <p><strong>Id:</strong> {{ item.id}}</p>
    <p><strong>Key:</strong>{{ item.key}}</p>
</div>
```

for more information, you can refer https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html